# Disabling Toolbar in Layout View using Python AddIn of ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I'm trying to disable a toolbar with nested menus and buttons when an mxd is in layout view, but it's not working.  I also get no output in the ArcGIS python window when I switch to layout view.

Anyone have any ideas?

Using: ArcGIS 10.2.2, Python 2.7

Code:

```
import arcpy  
import pythonaddins  

class FishButton(object):  
    """Implementation for WTF_addin.fish_button (Button)"""  
    def __init__(self):  
        self.enabled = True  
##        self.checked = False  
    def onClick(self):  
        self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')  
##        layer = r'\\msds.wv.de\dfsroot\HV\GROUP\Gis\DATEN\wvdat\Querbauwerke\Fischaufstieg.lyr'  
        layer = r'G:\Gis\DATEN\wvdat\Querbauwerke\Fischaufstieg.lyr'  
        activeDataFrame = self.mxd.activeView  
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(self.mxd, activeDataFrame)[0]  
        if arcpy.Exists(layer):  
            layerToAdd = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer)  
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layerToAdd, 'TOP')  
        else:  
            warningButton = pythonaddins.MessageBox("Die Datei ist nicht verfugbar.\nBitte kontaktieren Sie die GIS Abteilung.", "Datei nicht verfugbar", 0)  
        pass  

class changeToolState(object):  
    """Implementation for WTF_addin.disable (Extension)"""  
    def __init__(self):  
        # For performance considerations, please remove all unused methods in this class.  
        self.enabled = True  
    def activeViewChanged(self):  
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')  
            active_view = mxd.activeView  
            if active_view == 'PAGE_LAYOUT':  
                WTF_toolbar.enabled = False  
                print 'button has been disabled...'  
            else:  
                WTF_toolbar.enabled = True  
                print 'button re-enabled...'  
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()  
            return
```

And the corresponding config.xml:

```
<ESRI.Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.esri.com/Desktop/AddIns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Name>WTF</Name><AddInID>{8ed28a7b-5aa3-4474-baa5-7674acbb350a}</AddInID><Description>New Addin</Description><Version>0.1</Version><Image /><Author>Untitled</Author><Company>Untitled</Company><Date>04/27/2016</Date><Targets><Target name="Desktop" version="10.2" /></Targets><AddIn language="PYTHON" library="WTF_addin.py" namespace="WTF_addin"><ArcMap>  
    <Commands>  
        <Button caption="Fish" category="WTF" class="FishButton" id="WTF_addin.fish_button" image="" message="" tip=""><Help heading="" /></Button>  
        </Commands>  
    <Extensions>  
        <Extension autoLoad="true" category="WTF" class="changeToolState" description="" id="WTF_addin.disable" name="Disable" productName="Disable" showInExtensionDialog="true" />  
        </Extensions>  
    <Toolbars>  
        <Toolbar caption="WTF_Toolbar" category="WTF" id="WTF_addin.WTF_toolbar" showInitially="true"><Items><Menu refID="WTF_addin.cat_menu" /></Items></Toolbar>  
        </Toolbars>  
    <Menus>  
        <Menu caption="Category" category="WTF" id="WTF_addin.cat_menu" isRootMenu="false" isShortcutMenu="false" separator="false"><Items><Button refID="WTF_addin.fish_button" /></Items></Menu>  
        </Menus>  
    </ArcMap></AddIn></ESRI.Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based off your code, it sounds like you're trying to disable a button rather than an entire toolbar.

Instead of `WTF_toolbar.enabled = False` do `fish_button.enabled = False` to disable the button. Same goes for `WTF_toolbar.enabled = True`.

There is more info in the help for [Managing the state of Python add-in types](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/managing-the-state-of-add-in-types.htm)

Comment: Thanks -- trying to disable the entire toolbar.  The print statements were copied in from somewhere else.

Comment: I am trying this. Did you got it working? from link that @freshmints provided: "...The enabled property is available for buttons, tools, and combo boxes." nothing about toolbars and it is not workin for my toolbar.